# Why "csvquery" package in python cannot be found?

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, modulenotfounderror

I've just installed csvquery1.1.3 and the installation process was successful. However, when I tried to import the package, import csvquery, then I received the following error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csvquery'

Is there any dependency that must be installed? How can I solve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you have two Python installed and you install module in one Python but you try to use it in second Python. Every Python use own modules. You can use `python -m pip install csvquery` to make sure you install it with correct Python.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this module (version 1.1.3) and it seems it is broken. It creates folder `csvquery-1.1.3.dist-info` with metadata but it doesn't create folder `csvquery` with real code.

If I install older version 1.1.2 then it creates folder `csvquery` with code and all works.

```
 pip install csvquery==1.1.2
```

---

**EDIT:**

I also downloaded module

```
 pip download csvquery
```

and get file `csvquery-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl` which I opend in `zip viewer` and it shows that there is no code in this module.

---

It seems at this moment you can only install `1.1.2` or you would have to download new version `csvquery.py` from `github` and put it manually in Python3 folder or in folder with your project.